# How to manipulate a returned datetime value in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I need to determine the average amount of time it takes our fulfillment team to process orders.

I plan to simply count the number of "seconds" between the "`PaidDateUtc`" and "`ShippedDateUtc`" value for each order, and then get the average.

My simplified query (minus the date range filter) is like this:

```
SELECT
    dbo.Shipment.ShippedDateUtc - dbo.[Order].PaidDateUtc AS TimeToFulfill
FROM
    dbo.[Order] INNER JOIN
    dbo.Shipment ON dbo.[Order].Id = dbo.Shipment.OrderId
```

The returned value looks like this:

```
1900-01-01 00:25:27.263
```

Which means:
**1 day, 1 hour, 25 minutes, and 27 seconds**

My question is: How can I manipulate it so that the returned value looks like this:

```
91527     --(total of seconds)
```

Comment: Tip: It is helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the syntax it looks like you're using either Microsoft SQL Server or Sybase, and if so then you could use the `DATEDIFF` function to get the amount of seconds between order and shipment like so:

```
SELECT      
    DATEDIFF(second, o.PaidDateUtc, s.ShippedDateUtc) AS TimeToFulfill
FROM 
    dbo.[Order] o
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Shipment s ON o.Id = s.OrderId
```

If you want the average number of seconds for each order wrap the `DATEDIFF` in `AVG()` with `group by order.id`:

```
SELECT
    o.id,    
    AVG(DATEDIFF(second, o.PaidDateUtc, s.ShippedDateUtc)) AS TimeToFulfill
FROM 
    dbo.[Order] o
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Shipment s ON o.Id = s.OrderId
GROUP BY 
    o.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `datediff()` for the time in seconds.  Your query will also look simpler if you use table aliases:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND, o.PaidDateUtc, s.ShippedDateUtc) AS TimeToFulfill
FROM dbo.[Order] o INNER JOIN
     dbo.Shipment s
     ON o.Id = s.OrderId;
```